# Azure subscription disabled in portal but active on the account.windowsazure.com

Tags: powershell, azure

I wanted to transfer resources (web apps) from an old subscription that had been disabled onto my new active subscription. I created a support request and they changed the disabled subscription into a Pay-As-You-Go -type and now using PowerShell I should be able to transfer my work over.

However I am still unable to access the old resource group in PS, for example when using Get-AzureRMResourceGroup only the new group I created comes up. I am also unable to do absolutely anything with my old work, even though the sub should now be active. I believe this is the reason I am unable to make the transfer. The title poses the actual dilemma that I believe is the root of my problems so, does anyone know a way to change this? Also I am happy to be corrected if I'm way off, or just be suggested an alternative approach.

Here's a silly picture to show the inconsistency I'm speaking of.

[image: Why disabled?]